# Error to save Custom coordinate system definition in QGIS Desktop 2.14.7

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to enter a coordinate reference system applicable to El Salvador in QGIS Desktop, but it doesn't save the coordinate system.
I am currently using version 2.14.7, however, I tried before using version 2.16.3., and the same error occurrs.

QGIS allows me to perform the test with the coordinate system. And then, I apply the changes. No error message was displayed, but when I back and looked for the new coordinate system, it wasn't found.

[image: Screen capture of t]

Comment: Works for me. Did you use the Filter search in Project Properties,CRS tab?

Comment: Thanks AndreJ for your response. I checked in filter search, and doesn't appear. My computer works with Windows 8.1 Pro, I'm not sure, if it could be linked to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the OSGEO4W version or install in a path without spaces. The problem could be related to blank spaces in the installation path.